# Determining the count of columns with a value greater than 0

Tags: t-sql, subquery, aggregate, common-table-expression, having

Ok guys/gals...

Here's my result set:

[image]

and here's the ultimate results set I want

[image]

to achieve the result, I am currently using *n* (3) subqueries... which is not ideal...

```
declare @userId int = 436
select
    (select count(PRODUCT_ID) from sl_suggested_asset where PRODUCT_ID > 0 and user_id = @userId) As 'PRODUCT_ID',
    (select count(DIGI_DOC_ID) from sl_suggested_asset where DIGI_DOC_ID > 0 and user_id = @userId) As 'DIGI_DOC_ID',
    (select count(QR_CODE_ID) from sl_suggested_asset where qr_code_id > 0  and user_id = @userId) As 'QR_CODE_ID'
```

what I would like is to use either a `cte` or  an `aggregate`...

here's what I was thinking...

```
select count(product_id), count(DIGI_DOC_ID), count(qr_code_id), user_id
from sl_suggested_asset
where user_id = 436
group by user_id
```

but this gives me the total number of rows...

so my `having` clause should be used but that means that I need to have the proper `group by predicate`... this is where I'm stuck...

here are some examples of what I've tried...

```
select 
    count(PRODUCT_ID) As 'PRODUCT_ID'
    , count(DIGI_DOC_ID) As 'DIGI_DOC_ID'
    , count(QR_CODE_ID) As 'QR_CODE_ID'
    , user_id
from sl_suggested_asset
where 
    PRODUCT_ID > 0
or
    DIGI_DOC_ID > 0
or
    QR_CODE_ID > 0
and
    user_id = 436
group by user_id
```

and I get...

[image]

... here I change the order of the `where` clause conditions...

```
select 
    count(PRODUCT_ID) As 'PRODUCT_ID'
    , count(DIGI_DOC_ID) As 'DIGI_DOC_ID'
    , count(QR_CODE_ID) As 'QR_CODE_ID'
    , user_id
from sl_suggested_asset
where 
    user_id = 436
and
    PRODUCT_ID > 0
or
    DIGI_DOC_ID > 0
or
    QR_CODE_ID > 0  
group by user_id
```

... and I get the same result as above ...

... now I change the `where` clause to `= 0` and get the same result, which means the `where` clause is being completely ignored...

```
select 
    count(PRODUCT_ID) As 'PRODUCT_ID'
    , count(DIGI_DOC_ID) As 'DIGI_DOC_ID'
    , count(QR_CODE_ID) As 'QR_CODE_ID'
    , user_id
from sl_suggested_asset
where 
    user_id = 436
and
    PRODUCT_ID = 0
or
    DIGI_DOC_ID = 0
or
    QR_CODE_ID = 0  
group by user_id
```

[image]

... lastly, if I change the `or`s to `and`s I get zero results ...

```
select 
    count(PRODUCT_ID) As 'PRODUCT_ID'
    , count(DIGI_DOC_ID) As 'DIGI_DOC_ID'
    , count(QR_CODE_ID) As 'QR_CODE_ID'
    , user_id
from sl_suggested_asset
where 
    user_id = 436
and
    PRODUCT_ID = 0
and
    DIGI_DOC_ID = 0
and
    QR_CODE_ID = 0  
group by user_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use some CASE STATEMENTS on the Query

`SELECT SUM(
          CASE 
          WHEN PRODUCT_ID > 0
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END
       ) as PRODUCT_ID ,
       SUM(
          CASE
          WHEN DIGI_DOC_ID>0
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END
       ) as DIGI_DOC_ID,
       SUM(
          CASE
          WHEN QR_CODE_ID>0
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END
       ) as QR_CODE_ID
FROM sl_SUGGESTED_ASSET
WHERE USER_ID =436`

Have a great day!

Comment: Or `case` _expressions_.